# How do you click on a ng-click with the webbrowser winforms control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control that connected to a website and parses the html to act upon it.

I came upon this tag:

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 grid_row grid_row_border_left grid_col_select ng-binding" ng-click="vmFASummary.navigateToDetails(summaryRow)" tabindex="0">01/2017</div>
```

I need to execute a click on the ng-click to go to the next page.

I have tried these code snippets to no avail.

```
    MethodInfo clickMethod = wbrElm.GetType().GetMethod("ng-click");
    clickMethod.Invoke(wbrElm, null);
    -----------------------------------------------
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
     {  
      webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("vmFASummary.navigateToDetails", new object[] { true });
     };
   ------------------------------------------------

   System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
   wbrElm.Document.InvokeScript("vmFASummary.navigateToDetails", new String[] { "summaryRow" });
   -----------------------------------------------
   wbrElm.RaiseEvent("ng-click");
   -----------------------------------------------
   wbrElm.InvokeMember("click");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {  
                    if(link !=null)
                    {

                        if (link.GetAttribute("ng-click").Equals("vmFASummary.navigateToDetails(summaryRow)"))
                        {

                            link.InvokeMember("Click");
                        }  
                    }
                }
```